# How to display a AJAX retrieved HTML code the correct way?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, parsing

I am using Rails 4 and the included jQuery library. I am in trouble when I have to display a AJAX retrieved HTML code on the page. That is, in a my view I have the following code:

```
# NOTES
#
# In my config/initializers/mime_types.rb file I have
# Mime::Type.register_alias 'text/html', :custom
#
# In my controller action I have:
#
# respond_to do |format|
#   format.custom { render(:partial => 'my_partial', :formats => :html) }
# end

link_to('show comment', comment_path(@comment, :format => :custom), :remote => true, :id => 'css_id')

$('#css_id').on('ajax:success', function(event, xhr, status) {
  $(this).html(xhr)
});
```

When the AJAX request is success then the output code is shown as-like the following (note: the `<b>` and `</b>` are not HTML parsed):

```
This is the <b>response html</b>.
```

By using FireBug I can see the response contains:

```
<div>This is the &lt;b&gt;response html&lt;/b&gt;.</div>
```

How can I make it to display `<b>` and `</b>` the correct way? That is, how can I make those to be evaluated as HTML code?

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving pure HTML back? Every time we've done something like this, we've been able to display the HTML on the page no problem - maybe the HTML is being URI encoded before you send it?

Comment: @Rich Peck - I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run the `html_safe` method on the server side, like this:

```
"This is the <b>response html</b>".html_safe
```

Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use format.js. Example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {
    render partial: "...", layout: false, locals: { ... }
  }
end
```

Comment: I use the `custom` format and I tried your code with it and it does *not* work as expected: the `<b>` and `</b>` are not HTML parsed.

Comment: I answered my question.